# How to access Bluetooth LE features of CYW43439 on Raspberry Pi Pico W?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, spi, bluetooth-low-energy, rp2040

Raspberry Pi Pico W comes with a chip, CYW43439, that is capable to do WiFi and Bluetooth (both Classic and LE). According to [Chapter 2.1 in Raspberry Pi Pico W:s datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/picow/pico-w-datasheet.pdf), GPIO24, GPIO25 and GPIO29 is used to communicate with the CYW43439 chip using SPI protocol.

[Chapter 4.2 in CYW43439:s datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_CYW43439_DataSheet_v03_00_EN-3074791.pdf) describes the generic SPI protocol interface, but Chapter 4 is the WLAN System Interface documentation. The same datasheet describes in Chapter 9.2, that UART is the interface for Bluetooth Host Controller Interface, HCI.

**When programming on the RP2040 microcontroller, I should use the wired GPIO pins to use SPI to interface CYW43439, but how can I access the Bluetooth HCI from this SPI protocol?**

There is a [pico C SDK](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/tree/1.5.0/src/rp2_common/pico_cyw43_driver) (that I don't really understand), but I would like to understand the interface to implement a driver in a different programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now learnt that this is an undocumented area, so the only option is to use the pico C SDK (e.g. [the suggestions in this issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/issues/1240)).

I will consider to use a nRF chip instead, since they appear to be better documented when it comes to Bluetooth.